# RT3090 wifi connection does not connect PCIe long time

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, ralink

My Wifi connection does not last long, just a few minutes, sometimes seconds nothing else.
My Network Ethernet card has been corrupted by power failure and errors at startup, but eth0.
In Windows 10 all perfect with the Wifi, I can not connect via Ethernet in Windows. Please help me?? And I looked and I got tired of searching the web.

Comment: lspci: 03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Comment: could you make any progress about this issue?